Ender 3 shut down with ”Err: MAXTEMP: Bed"
While I was printing my printer randomly started letting out a long loud beep. So, I turned it off and on now every time I turn it on it gives that error message and won’t let me do anything else. I tried to replace the thermistor on the hot end but it keeps on showing the error code. I think I have to replace the thermistor on the bed but I’m not sure how to do that.


I presume the bed doesn't feel hot, therefore something is interfering with the printer's ability to sense it's bed temperature.
Two possibilities come to mind:

The bed's temperature sensor is broken/damaged or otherwise returning a false reading.  In this case, replacement of that sensor is your only option.

The wiring is damaged between sensor and mainboard.  Given the printer is at least 5 years old, that's a lot of flexing on the wire and terminations.


If I were you, I'd turn the printer over, open the mainboard cover, and identify the leads to the bed's thermistor.  And the leads to the print-head thermistor.  Take a photo, and then disconnect the leads.
Then get a multimeter, set to Ohms, and compare the resistance of each thermistor.  They should be around 100 kOhms when at room temperature.   If you're getting close to 0 or "many megaohms" then the sensor is faulty and needs replacement.   Compare resistance of both thermistors to make sure you're getting a good value and  your method is sound.
If the resistance is close to zero then you have a short.  That may be through a gap in the wiring, but is more likely a dead sensor.
If the resistance is super high, that could easily be a break in the wire.  Pull the wires out and look for sharp bends/kinks.  If the wire is faulty, you may get away with replacing the wires to the existing sensor.  Do use stranded wire no-thinner than your existing wires.
Good luck !

This may be helpful, but it is talking about a print-head thermistor:



